# If element is in array delete, else push

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using HTML + JS + CSS to create a webpage. I am aiming to create an array that can filter a csv for certain values. In doing so I need column headers, which is what this function is trying to make.

I have 3 buttons like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick='pushBx()'>Bx</button>
<button type="button" onclick='pushBy()'>By</button>
<button type="button" onclick='pushBz()'>Bz</button>
```

That fire a function like this:

```
function pushBz() {
  clickedBusinesses.push('Bz');

  console.log(clickedBusinesses);
}
```

This pushes to:

```
var clickedBusinesses = []
```

But my console looks like this:

```
["By", "By", "Bz", "Bz", "Bz", "Bz"]
```

I would like a to make a function that, on button press, deletes the id if already in the array, else it'll push it to the array, so my array looks more like this:

```
["By", "Bz"]
```

I have tried to build an if statement but it doesn't work.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with this approach;

```js
function pushBz() {
  if(clickedBusinesses.includes('Bz')){
     // removing the element from that array
     clickedBusinesses = clickedBusinesses.filter( cb => cb !== 'Bz' )
  }else{
     clickedBusinesses.push('Bz')
  }
  console.log(clickedBusinesses);
}
```

---

However your code can be improved a little by using a single function, instead of three similar function with hard-coded values;

```html
<button type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx")'>Bx</button>
<button type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("By")'>By</button>
<button type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bz")'>Bz</button>
```

and that fires a function like this:

```js
function toggleClickedBuz( bizStr ) {
  if(clickedBusinesses.includes(bizStr)){
     // removing the element from that array
     clickedBusinesses = clickedBusinesses.filter( cb => cb !== bizStr )
  }else{
     clickedBusinesses.push(bizStr)
  }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: clickedBusinesses.includes is not a function
    at pushBz (index.js:42)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:23)

Comment: @AliShahVis that problem is definitely not from my code, you may somewhere else in your code, assigning something else to that `clickedBusinesses` since that error rises when `clickedBusinesses` is anything but an array, say `undefined`, `null`, `object` , ...

Answer (score 0):

Unless the order of the items is actually important, use a plain object (or a `Set` if you're feeling fancy:

```
const clickedBusinesses = {};
function toggle(business) {
  clickedBusinesses[business] = !clickedBusinesses[business];
}
function pushBz() {
  toggle('Bz');
  console.log(clickedBusinesses);
}
```

This way `clickedBusinesses` will have a `true` value for all enabled businesses, or `false` (or no value at all) for disabled ones.

To get an array out of that,

```
function getClickedBusinesses() {
  return Object.keys(clickedBusinesses).filter(key => clickedBusinesses[key]);
}
```

will return (e.g.) `['Bz']`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so fast. I have tried your solution but I am not sure how the toggle(business) function works. I don't have a business array defined ['Bx', 'By', 'Bz']. Does it need this? 

Getting this also from console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: pushBz is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:23)

Comment: You don't need the array. Did you also copy in the new version of `pushBz()` from above? I don't see how you'd get that reference error otherwise.

Comment: I just copied that in, in the right order. I am getting console.log() to open a set of whether the button is true or false. Struggling to input the final function to return clickedBusinesses within my button press functions

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is removing dublicate items after you update the array

Define the function first:

```
var removeDublicate = function(arrayToBeCleaned){
   var uniqueArray = [];
   $.each(arrayToBeCleaned, function(i, el){
       if($.inArray(el, uniqueArray) === -1) uniqueArray.push(el);
   });
   return uniqueArray;
}
```

Then use the function:

```
var myCrowdedArray = ["A","A","A","B","B","C","C"];

var uniqueArray = removeDublicate(myCrowdedArray)
```

For your case:

```
function pushBz() {
  clickedBusinesses.push('Bz');
  clickedBusinesses = removeDublicate(clickedBusinesses)
  console.log(clickedBusinesses);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single function with value as parameter and seach fro the value and add or splice the array.

```js
function push(value) { 
    var index = array.indexOf(value);
    
    if (index === -1) array.push(value);
    else array.splice(index, 1);
    
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = array.join(' ');
}

var array = [];
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="push('Bx');">Bx</button>
<button type="button" onclick="push('By')">By</button>
<button type="button" onclick="push('Bz')">Bz</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think it is better to use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Your function should look like this

```js
clickedBusinesses = new Set();

function pushBz() {
  if (clickedBusinesses.has('Bz'))
    clickedBusinesses.delete('Bz');
  else
    clickedBusinesses.add('Bz');
}
```

Set has better performance when you need to remains unique values. When you need to convert it to an array you can use `[...set]`